# Menu responsivo não fecha quando seleciona elemento

Tags: html5, css3, layout-responsivo

Fiz um menu responsivo num site one page.

A parte de rolagem da pagina está funcionando normalmente, mas o menu só fecha se o usuário clicar novamente no ícone do menu.

Preciso que o menu feche quando o usuário selecionar um dos elementos do nav.

```js
 $('.efeito-desliza').click(function () {
            $('html, body').animate({
                scrollTop: $($(this).attr('href')).offset().top
            }, 1000);
            return false;
 });
```

```html
 <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
   <div class="container">
     <div class="navbar-header">
       <button type="button" data-target="#navbarCollapse" data-toggle="collapse" class="navbar-toggle">
         <span class="sr-only">Navegação Responsiva</span>

       </button>
       <a href="#home" class="img-responsive efeito-desliza navbar-brand"><img class="img-responsive"
                                                                               src="img/logo.png"></a>
     </div>
     <div id="navbarCollapse" class="menu-scroll collapse navbar-collapse menu">
       <ul class="nav navbar-nav ">
         <li><a class="efeito-desliza" href="#bu">SOLUÇÕES</a></li>
         <li><a class="efeito-desliza" href="#div-quemsomos">QUEM SOMOS</a></li>
         <li><a class="efeito-desliza" href="#depoimentos">DEPOIMENTOS</a></li>
         <li><a class="efeito-desliza" href="#contato">CONTATO</a></li>
       </ul>
     </div>
   </div>
    </nav>
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Faz uma programação com o evento de click em cima do elemento clicado para fechar o menu. Exemplo:

```
$('.efeito-desliza').click(function () {
            $('html, body').animate({
                scrollTop: $($(this).attr('href')).offset().top
            }, 1000);
            $('.navbar-toggle').click(); // FAZ UM CLIQUE NO BOTAO QUE CHAMA O MENU PARA OCULTAR O MENU
            return false;

 });
```

*Obs: se não for .navbar-toggle o botao que clica e abre o menu, então mude para o id deste botao ex: `$('#idBotao').click();`*